# Sorting files to subfolder unless single, how to fix huge efficiency issue?

Tags: sorting, batch-file, batch-processing

I have this script that sorts files to a folder tree called `series` which is populated by a simple "SERIES NAME" subdirectories containing the files. If only one file gets put into a folder it will be reverted or as I like to call "unnested". It also contains one special folder `PILOT EPISODES` where most of the orphans go (others can stay). Here is the code:

```
:: precautions
@cd /d d:\videos\series
@if /i not "%cd%"=="d:\videos\series" echo invalid series dir. && exit /b
@if not exist "pilot episodes" echo pilot episodes dir missing. && exit /b
@if not exist "d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd" echo lootname missing. && exit /b

:: re-sort pilots every now and then
@if "%time:7,4%"=="7,77" move "pilot episodes\*01?01*" . >nul && echo pilot episodes unnested

:: sort by name into dedicated folders
@for %%g in (*.mp4 *.mkv *.m4v *.avi *.flv *.mpg *.mpeg *.mpe *.wmv *.mov *.ts *.m2ts *.vob *.3gp *.rm) do @call :nest "%%g"

:: revert folders with single episode
@for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir /s /b /ad') do @dir "%%g" | findstr /c:" 1 File" >nul && @move "%%g\*" . >nul
@for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do @rd "%%d" 2>nul

:: single pilots to dedicated folder
@if exist "pilot episodes" for %%g in (*01e01* *01e00* *01x01*) do @move "%%g" "pilot episodes"
@exit /b

:nest
:: this call extrapolates show name from filename
@call d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd %1 data
@if not exist "%name%" mkdir "%name%"
@move %1 "%name%"
@if exist %1 echo moving "%~n1" to "%name%" failed. maybe a duplicate exists or file is being used?"
```

The massive problem is that this is a heavy process, especially when I sometimes have to move all pilots back to series root for re-sorting (in case more episodes have appeared for a show). It has to nest every one and then revert every one and move them back to pilots just to see if any new "pairing" was done. I wonder if there is a way to skip all this unnecessary work and still keep it relatively simple?

edit:

This is the `lootname.cmd` file referred in the script. It does a bit more than just extrapolate the name for series sorting. It also detects year, season and episode which it uses to apply further restrictions to `filebot` renaming (do fake rename and compare to original before real rename). I may be way paranoid here but I don't trust filebot much. As a side feature it also renames the file to include `making of` if it's in a folder named `extras` or `featurettes`. Anyway using the `data` loop it bypasses all but the extrapolations which are the only thing that is used by my series sorter above.

```
if "%~2"=="data" call :data "%~n1" data & exit /b
cd /d "%~dp1"
if not "%cd%\"=="%~dp1" echo dir %~dp1 not found && exit /b

:: detect extras (from path) and rename to include movie name from parent folder
:: bug: this puts double "making of " to beginning of the first file for some reason.
echo %1 | find /i "extras" >nul && call :data %2
echo %1 | find /i "featurettes" >nul && call :data %2
echo %1 | find /i "extras" >nul && ren %1 "Making of %name% - %~nx1" && exit /b
echo %1 | find /i "featurettes" >nul && ren %1 "Making of %name% - %~nx1" && exit /b

:: regular job start (show and film only)
call :data "%~n1"
if "%type%"=="misc" echo unable to rename without tags "%~n1" && exit /b

:: prep fake temp file
set tempdir=%temp%\%date:~3,2%%date:~6,2%%date:~11,2%%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
md "%tempdir%" && copy /y nul "%tempdir%\%~nx1" >nul

:: variables (to shorten lines)
set fb=c:\progra~1\filebot\filebot
if "%type%"=="film" set cf=--db TheMovieDb --format "{n} ({y}) {director} {genres} r{rating} {vf} {vc} {ac} {imdbid}"
if "%type%"=="show" set cf=--db TheTVDb --format "{n} {s00e00} {t} {vf} {vc} {ac} {imdbid}"

:: rename fake temp file
%fb% -rename "%tempdir%\%~nx1" --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul
for /r "%tempdir%" %%i in (*) do set "new=%%~ni"
if "%~n1"=="%new%" echo rename manually "%~n1" && exit /b

:: if as expected rename for real
if "%type%"=="film" echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%name% (%year%)" >nul && goto 4real
if "%type%"=="show" if not "%year%"=="" echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%name% (%year%) %ss%%ep%" >nul && goto 4real
if "%type%"=="show" if "%year%"=="" echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%name% %ss%%ep%" >nul && goto 4real
echo rename "%~n1" failed && exit /b
exit /b

:4real
%fb% -rename %1 --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul
if not exist %1 echo successfully renamed "%~n1"
exit /b

:data
set ss=
set ep=
set year=
set type=misc
set name=%~1

:: sanitize
set name=%name:.= %
set name=%name:_= %
set name=%name: - = %
set name=%name: - Copy.=.%
set name=%name: (original)=%
set name=%name:(1)=%
set name=%name:(2)=%
set name=%name:[1]=%
set name=%name:[2]=%
set name=%name:(=%
set name=%name:)=%
set name=%name:[=%
set name=%name:]=%
set name=%name:pbs =%
set name=%name:bbc =%
set name=%name: the series=%
set name=%name:  = %

:: episode tags as variables + cut
set name=%name:e199=& set ep=E199& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e198=& set ep=E198& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e197=& set ep=E197& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e196=& set ep=E196& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e195=& set ep=E195& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e194=& set ep=E194& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e193=& set ep=E193& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e192=& set ep=E192& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e191=& set ep=E191& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e190=& set ep=E190& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e189=& set ep=E189& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e188=& set ep=E188& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e187=& set ep=E187& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e186=& set ep=E186& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e185=& set ep=E185& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e184=& set ep=E184& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e183=& set ep=E183& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e182=& set ep=E182& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e181=& set ep=E181& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e180=& set ep=E180& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e179=& set ep=E179& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e178=& set ep=E178& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e177=& set ep=E177& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e176=& set ep=E176& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e175=& set ep=E175& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e174=& set ep=E174& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e173=& set ep=E173& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e172=& set ep=E172& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e171=& set ep=E171& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e170=& set ep=E170& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e169=& set ep=E169& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e168=& set ep=E168& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e167=& set ep=E167& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e166=& set ep=E166& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e165=& set ep=E165& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e164=& set ep=E164& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e163=& set ep=E163& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e162=& set ep=E162& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e161=& set ep=E161& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e160=& set ep=E160& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e159=& set ep=E159& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e158=& set ep=E158& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e157=& set ep=E157& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e156=& set ep=E156& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e155=& set ep=E155& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e154=& set ep=E154& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e153=& set ep=E153& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e152=& set ep=E152& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e151=& set ep=E151& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e150=& set ep=E150& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e149=& set ep=E149& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e148=& set ep=E148& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e147=& set ep=E147& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e146=& set ep=E146& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e145=& set ep=E145& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e144=& set ep=E144& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e143=& set ep=E143& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e142=& set ep=E142& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e141=& set ep=E141& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e140=& set ep=E140& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e139=& set ep=E139& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e138=& set ep=E138& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e137=& set ep=E137& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e136=& set ep=E136& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e135=& set ep=E135& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e134=& set ep=E134& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e133=& set ep=E133& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e132=& set ep=E132& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e131=& set ep=E131& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e130=& set ep=E130& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e129=& set ep=E129& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e128=& set ep=E128& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e127=& set ep=E127& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e126=& set ep=E126& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e125=& set ep=E125& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e124=& set ep=E124& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e123=& set ep=E123& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e122=& set ep=E122& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e121=& set ep=E121& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e120=& set ep=E120& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e119=& set ep=E119& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e118=& set ep=E118& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e117=& set ep=E117& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e116=& set ep=E116& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e115=& set ep=E115& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e114=& set ep=E114& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e113=& set ep=E113& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e112=& set ep=E112& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e111=& set ep=E111& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e110=& set ep=E110& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e109=& set ep=E109& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e108=& set ep=E108& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e107=& set ep=E107& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e106=& set ep=E106& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e105=& set ep=E105& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e104=& set ep=E104& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e103=& set ep=E103& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e102=& set ep=E102& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e101=& set ep=E101& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e100=& set ep=E100& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e99=& set ep=E99& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e98=& set ep=E98& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e97=& set ep=E97& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e96=& set ep=E96& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e95=& set ep=E95& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e94=& set ep=E94& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e93=& set ep=E93& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e92=& set ep=E92& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e91=& set ep=E91& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e90=& set ep=E90& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e89=& set ep=E89& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e88=& set ep=E88& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e87=& set ep=E87& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e86=& set ep=E86& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e85=& set ep=E85& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e84=& set ep=E84& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e83=& set ep=E83& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e82=& set ep=E82& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e81=& set ep=E81& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e80=& set ep=E80& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e79=& set ep=E79& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e78=& set ep=E78& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e77=& set ep=E77& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e76=& set ep=E76& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e75=& set ep=E75& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e74=& set ep=E74& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e73=& set ep=E73& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e72=& set ep=E72& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e71=& set ep=E71& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e70=& set ep=E70& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e69=& set ep=E69& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e68=& set ep=E68& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e67=& set ep=E67& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e66=& set ep=E66& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e65=& set ep=E65& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e64=& set ep=E64& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e63=& set ep=E63& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e62=& set ep=E62& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e61=& set ep=E61& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e60=& set ep=E60& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e59=& set ep=E59& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e58=& set ep=E58& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e57=& set ep=E57& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e56=& set ep=E56& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e55=& set ep=E55& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e54=& set ep=E54& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e53=& set ep=E53& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e52=& set ep=E52& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e51=& set ep=E51& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e50=& set ep=E50& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e49=& set ep=E49& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e48=& set ep=E48& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e47=& set ep=E47& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e46=& set ep=E46& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e45=& set ep=E45& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e44=& set ep=E44& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e43=& set ep=E43& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e42=& set ep=E42& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e41=& set ep=E41& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e40=& set ep=E40& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e39=& set ep=E39& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e38=& set ep=E38& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e37=& set ep=E37& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e36=& set ep=E36& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e35=& set ep=E35& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e34=& set ep=E34& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e33=& set ep=E33& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e32=& set ep=E32& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e31=& set ep=E31& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e30=& set ep=E30& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e29=& set ep=E29& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e28=& set ep=E28& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e27=& set ep=E27& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e26=& set ep=E26& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e25=& set ep=E25& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e24=& set ep=E24& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e23=& set ep=E23& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e22=& set ep=E22& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e21=& set ep=E21& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e20=& set ep=E20& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e19=& set ep=E19& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e18=& set ep=E18& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e17=& set ep=E17& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e16=& set ep=E16& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e15=& set ep=E15& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e14=& set ep=E14& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e13=& set ep=E13& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e12=& set ep=E12& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e11=& set ep=E11& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e10=& set ep=E10& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e09=& set ep=E09& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e08=& set ep=E08& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e07=& set ep=E07& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e06=& set ep=E06& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e05=& set ep=E05& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e04=& set ep=E04& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e03=& set ep=E03& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e02=& set ep=E02& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e01=& set ep=E01& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:e00=& set ep=E00& set type=show& rem %

:: season tags as variables + cut
set name=%name: s00=& set ss=S00& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s01=& set ss=S01& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s02=& set ss=S02& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s03=& set ss=S03& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s04=& set ss=S04& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s05=& set ss=S05& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s06=& set ss=S06& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s07=& set ss=S07& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s08=& set ss=S08& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s09=& set ss=S09& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s10=& set ss=S10& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s11=& set ss=S11& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s12=& set ss=S12& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s13=& set ss=S13& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s14=& set ss=S14& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s15=& set ss=S15& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s16=& set ss=S16& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s17=& set ss=S17& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s18=& set ss=S18& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s19=& set ss=S19& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s20=& set ss=S20& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s21=& set ss=S21& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s22=& set ss=S22& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s23=& set ss=S23& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s24=& set ss=S24& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s25=& set ss=S25& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s26=& set ss=S26& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s27=& set ss=S27& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s28=& set ss=S28& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s29=& set ss=S29& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name: s30=& set ss=S30& set type=show& rem %

set name=%name:season 1 =& set ss=S01& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 2 =& set ss=S02& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 3 =& set ss=S03& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 4 =& set ss=S04& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 5 =& set ss=S05& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 6 =& set ss=S06& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 7 =& set ss=S07& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 8 =& set ss=S08& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:season 9 =& set ss=S09& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 1 =& set ss=S01& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 2 =& set ss=S02& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 3 =& set ss=S03& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 4 =& set ss=S04& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 5 =& set ss=S05& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 6 =& set ss=S06& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 7 =& set ss=S07& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 8 =& set ss=S08& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:series 9 =& set ss=S09& set type=show& rem %

set name=%name:1of=& set ep=E01& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:2of=& set ep=E02& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:3of=& set ep=E03& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:4of=& set ep=E04& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:5of=& set ep=E05& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:6of=& set ep=E06& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:7of=& set ep=E07& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:8of=& set ep=E08& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:9of=& set ep=E09& set type=show& rem %

set name=%name:x01=x& set ep=E01& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x02=x& set ep=E02& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x03=x& set ep=E03& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x04=x& set ep=E04& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x05=x& set ep=E05& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x06=x& set ep=E06& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x07=x& set ep=E07& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x08=x& set ep=E08& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x09=x& set ep=E09& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:x10=x& set ep=E10& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:01x=& set ss=S01& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:02x=& set ss=S02& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:03x=& set ss=S03& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:04x=& set ss=S04& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:05x=& set ss=S05& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:06x=& set ss=S06& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:07x=& set ss=S07& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:08x=& set ss=S08& set type=show& rem %
set name=%name:09x=& set ss=S09& set type=show& rem %

:: lastly year tags as variables + cut
set name=%name: 1963=& set year=1963& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1964=& set year=1964& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1965=& set year=1965& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1966=& set year=1966& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1967=& set year=1967& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1968=& set year=1968& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1969=& set year=1969& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1970=& set year=1970& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1971=& set year=1971& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1972=& set year=1972& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1973=& set year=1973& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1974=& set year=1974& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1975=& set year=1975& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1976=& set year=1976& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1977=& set year=1977& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1978=& set year=1978& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1979=& set year=1979& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1980=& set year=1980& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1981=& set year=1981& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1982=& set year=1982& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1983=& set year=1983& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1984=& set year=1984& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1985=& set year=1985& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1986=& set year=1986& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1987=& set year=1987& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1988=& set year=1988& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1989=& set year=1989& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1990=& set year=1990& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1991=& set year=1991& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1992=& set year=1992& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1993=& set year=1993& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1994=& set year=1994& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1995=& set year=1995& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1996=& set year=1996& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1997=& set year=1997& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1998=& set year=1998& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 1999=& set year=1999& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2000=& set year=2000& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2001=& set year=2001& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2002=& set year=2002& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2003=& set year=2003& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2004=& set year=2004& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2005=& set year=2005& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2006=& set year=2006& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2007=& set year=2007& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2008=& set year=2008& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2009=& set year=2009& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2010=& set year=2010& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2011=& set year=2011& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2012=& set year=2012& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2013=& set year=2013& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2014=& set year=2014& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2015=& set year=2015& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2016=& set year=2016& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2017=& set year=2017& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2018=& set year=2018& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2019=& set year=2019& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2020=& set year=2020& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2021=& set year=2021& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2022=& set year=2022& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2023=& set year=2023& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2024=& set year=2024& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2025=& set year=2025& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2026=& set year=2026& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2027=& set year=2027& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2028=& set year=2028& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2029=& set year=2029& if not defined type set type=film& rem %
set name=%name: 2030=& set year=2030& if not defined type set type=film& rem %

:: capitalize
set name=%name:a=A%
set name=%name:b=B%
set name=%name:c=C%
set name=%name:d=D%
set name=%name:e=E%
set name=%name:f=F%
set name=%name:g=G%
set name=%name:h=H%
set name=%name:i=I%
set name=%name:j=J%
set name=%name:k=K%
set name=%name:l=L%
set name=%name:m=M%
set name=%name:n=N%
set name=%name:o=O%
set name=%name:p=P%
set name=%name:q=Q%
set name=%name:r=R%
set name=%name:s=S%
set name=%name:t=T%
set name=%name:u=U%
set name=%name:v=V%
set name=%name:w=W%
set name=%name:x=X%
set name=%name:y=Y%
set name=%name:z=Z%
set name=%name:ä=Ä%
set name=%name:ö=Ö%
```

Comment: I can't help thinking you'd be much better off putting the list of files into a Python/Perl script to organise rather than moving files around in a filesystem and using just about the most pathetic scripting language ever invented... just my 2 cents. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know any other languages so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
:: precautions
:: cd /d d:\videos\series
:: if /i not "%cd%"=="d:\videos\series" echo invalid series dir. && exit /b
:: if not exist "pilot episodes" echo pilot episodes dir missing. && exit /b
::if not exist "d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd" echo lootname missing. && exit /b
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%g IN ('dir /s/b /a-d *.mp4 *.mkv *.m4v *.avi *.flv *.mpg *.mpeg *.mpe *.wmv *.mov *.ts *.m2ts *.vob *.3gp *.rm') DO (
rem CALL d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd %1 data
 CALL :extract "%%~ng"
 ECHO !name!*%%g
)
)>tempfile.txt
ECHO zzzzzzzzz*zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz>>tempfile.txt
:: File has format extractedname*fullname
SET "lastname="
SET "pilot="

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=*" %%g IN ('sort tempfile.txt') DO (
 IF /i "%%g"=="!lastname!" (
  REM more than one entry with same extractedname
  IF DEFINED pilot (
   REM first episode found - directory to be created
   IF NOT EXIST "%%g" ECHO MD "%cd%\%%g"
   REM move pilot to the directory if required
   IF /i "!pilotdir!" neq "%cd%\%%g\" ECHO MOVE "!pilot!" "%cd%\%%g\"
   REM done with pilot
   SET "pilot="
  )
   IF /i "%%~dph" neq "%cd%\%%g\" ECHO MOVE "%%h" "%cd%\%%g\"
 ) ELSE (
  REM first occurrence of extractedname
  IF DEFINED pilot (
   REM pilot following pilot - only pilot 
   IF /i "!pilotdir!" neq "%cd%\PILOT EPISODES\" ECHO MOVE "!pilot!" "%cd%\PILOT EPISODES\"
  )
  SET "pilot=%%h"
  SET "pilotdir=%%~dph"
  SET "lastname=%%g"
 )
)
)>whattodo.bat
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :eof
```

Interesting exercise.

Cautions with the above code:

I've commented-out all of the precautions as they don't apply to my system.

I assumed that `d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd %1 data` would establish a variable called `name` depending on the filename supplied. I substituted a routine for testing called `:extract` and passed it simply the name part of the filename. Naturally, your `%1` here would need to be changed too.

I did not make any test with filenames which contained the known batch-troublemakers like `!`.

I've assumed that any file found which returns a unique `[series]name` is a pilot.

So - first, do a complete directory-scan and create a file which contains lines of the format `seriesname*fullfilename` - noting that the separator `*` is an invalid filename-character.

Having now obtained this list in this format, sort it and invoke the second `for` routine. The `for` will assign the seriesname to `%%g` and the full filename to `%%h`. The file will consist of a sequence of lines `PEEEPEPEEPPEE` where `P` is a "pilot" - where the seriesname changes.

So - if `%%g` is different from the previous `%%g`, then we have a new pilot, so save its seriesname and full filename and also the directory part of the full filename (as it's really easy to access at the time).

If we have an episode in the same series next, `%%g` will match, so we "create" the destination directory if it doesn't already exist and "move" the 'pilot' filename there (if it isn't already in the correct directory) then we're done with this pilot, so clear the variable `pilot` (so the `move` isn't repeated). And finally, move the episode to the directory.

If we have a pilot of the next series, then effectively we do the same thing, but if `pilot` is already set, then we need to need to move that to the `pilot episodes` directory (if it isn't already there) as a singleton.

We *could* be left with just a pilot episode when the filelist runs out (ie. the last on the list is pilot-only). To get over this, simply add a dummy record of all-`z` with the `*` separator. This will sort last and appear to be a new seriesname zzzzz... which we can ignore, since it's a dummy.

And out pops a file `whattodo.bat` with the `move`s and `md`s required to do the task.

Now - if you were to change all of those `move`s to `call chkmove` then a routine could be written to check that the move was successful. Same idea with the `md`s.

Oh - btw: a single `@echo off` at the beginning of a batch will render all those `@`s redundant. The `@` simply means `don't echo this instruction`

---

[replacement for name-extraction routine]

```dos
if "%~2"=="data" call :data "%~n1" data & ECHO processed %1 & exit /b
@cd /d "%~dp1"
@if not "%cd%\"=="%~dp1" echo dir %~dp1 not found && exit /b

:: detect extras (from path) and rename to include movie name from parent folder
:: bug: this puts double "making of " to beginning of the first file for some reason.
@echo %1 | find /i "extras" >nul && call :data %2
@echo %1 | find /i "featurettes" >nul && call :data %2
@echo %1 | find /i "extras" >nul && ren %1 "Making of %name% - %~nx1" && exit /b
@echo %1 | find /i "featurettes" >nul && ren %1 "Making of %name% - %~nx1" && exit /b

:: regular job start (show and film only)
@call :data "%~n1"
@if "%type%"=="misc" echo unable to rename without tags "%~n1" && exit /b
@echo "%name%" | find /i "ancient aliens" >nul && echo %~n1 can't be renamed automatically && exit /b
@echo "%name%" | find /i "impractical jokers" >nul && echo %~n1 can't be renamed automatically && exit /b

:: prep fake temp file
@set tempdir=%temp%\%date:~3,2%%date:~6,2%%date:~11,2%%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
@md "%tempdir%" && @copy /y nul "%tempdir%\%~nx1" >nul

:: variables (to shorten lines)
@set fb=c:\progra~1\filebot\filebot
@if "%type%"=="film" set cf=--db TheMovieDb --format "{n} ({y}) {director} {genres} r{rating} {vf} {vc} {ac} {imdbid}"
@if "%type%"=="show" set cf=--db TheTVDb --format "{n} {s00e00} {t} {vf} {vc} {ac} {imdbid}"

:: rename fake temp file
@%fb% -rename "%tempdir%\%~nx1" --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul
@for /r "%tempdir%" %%i in (*) do @set "new=%%~ni"
@if "%~n1"=="%new%" echo rename manually "%~n1" && exit /b

:: if as expected rename for real
@if "%type%"=="film" echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%name% (%year%)" >nul && @goto 4real
@if "%type%"=="show" if not "%year%"=="" echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%name% (%year%) %ss%%ep%" >nul && @goto 4real
@if "%type%"=="show" if "%year%"=="" echo %%new:^&=^^^&%% | findstr /i /b /c:"%name% %ss%%ep%" >nul && @goto 4real
@echo rename "%~n1" failed && exit /b
@exit /b

:4real
@%fb% -rename %1 --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul
@if not exist %1 echo successfully renamed "%~n1"
@exit /b


:: =============================================================================================================================
::    FROM FILENAME EXTRAPOLATE NAME AND POSSIBLE YEAR OR SEASON AND EPISODE PLUS DETERMINE TYPE AS SHOW, FILM OR MISC.
:: =============================================================================================================================

:data
set ss=
set ep=
set year=
set type=misc
set name=%~1

:: sanitize
set name=%name:.= %
set name=%name:_= %
set name=%name: - Copy.=.%
set name=%name: - = %
set name=%name: (original)=%
set name=%name:(1)=%
set name=%name:(2)=%
set name=%name:[1]=%
set name=%name:[2]=%
set name=%name:(=%
set name=%name:)=%
set name=%name:[=%
set name=%name:]=%
set name=%name:pbs =%
set name=%name:bbc =%
set name=%name: the series=%
set name=%name:  = %

:: detect type

echo %1 | FINDSTR /i /L "203 202 201 200 199 198 197 196" >nul&& set type=film
echo %1 | FINDSTR /i /L "0of 1of 2of 3of 4of 5of 6of 7of 8of 9of 0of" >nul&& set type=show

:: episode tags as variables + cut %

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%e IN (199,-1,10 ) DO SET "modname=!name:E%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E%%e=& set ep=E%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
FOR /L %%e IN (9,-1,1 ) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:E0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:%%eof=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:%%eof=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:x0%%e=!" 
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:x0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:0%%ex=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:0%%ex=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO skipep

:gotep
%setcmd%
ENDLOCAL &SET name=%name%&SET type=%type%&SET ep=%ep%

:skipep

:: ss tags as variables + cut

SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%e IN (30,-1,10 ) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:S%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:S%%e=& set ss=S%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (9,-1,1 ) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:S0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:S0%%e=& set ep=S0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO skipss

:gotss
%setcmd%
ENDLOCAL &SET name=%name%&SET type=%type%&SET ss=%ss%

:skipss


:: year tags as variables + cut
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%e IN (1963,1,2030) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:%%e=& set year=%%e& rem !"
  GOTO gotyear
 )
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO skipyear

:gotyear
%setcmd%
ENDLOCAL &SET name=%name%&SET year=%year%

:skipyear


SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%a IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO SET "name=!name:%%a=%%a!"
endlocal&SET name=%name%
set name=%name:ä=Ä%
set name=%name:ö=Ö%
GOTO :eof
```

Note: I only changed the name-extract part.

Comment : You need to sanitise `-copy.` before `-`. As it stood, the `-` would be removed first, so `- copy.` would never be found.

First, `findstr` allows you to locate any of member of a series of strings, so this should only execute `findstr` twice. Since it (and `find`) is an external routine, it's slow to use - hence, no doubt, the performance hit.

Note that the logic will provide a hit on year-numbers, setting `type` to `film` (at this point)

Next - analyse for E??? By employing `delayedexpansion` it's possible to feed in a set of values - in the `E` case, 199..10 - and by checking whether the substitution was effective, construct the strange `set` instruction (which I'd not seen before - and I'm not that sure I like it, but it seems to work...) and once that had been established, `goto` out of the loop since it's folly to examine the remaining possibilities.

With `ep`, if the loop exits without a hit, try again using `E0?` for `?` in 9..1 and follow that with `?of` `x0?` and `0?x`, constructing and exiting as required.

If it gets through all of that, no ep data is located, so simply skip to the next processing block as `ep` is not known. Since no changes have been made that we want to keep, we can simply `endlocal` to keep the setlocal/endlocal frame-stack under control.

If we exited the loop early, we've found the values required, so execute the command in `setcmd`, which will set `name`, `type` and `ep` appropriately. Since we want to keep those changes, we use a parsing trick to do so - *that* `endlocal` is followed by seemingly-redundant  `set` commands. It's important that all of these be on the same physical line because `cmd` will resolve the assignments to their current values, then execute the `endlocal` (removing the changes made to variables since the `setlocal`) and *then* assign the variables back to the values they had before the `endlocal`.

The remainder is more of the same, but using different key character sequences.

Finally, the capitalisation routine uses the fact that the *search-for-me* character is case-insensitive in a set-with-substitution statement, although the replacement is literal.

So - interesting exercise.

---

Another revision

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "tempfile=%temp%\somename"
SET "categories="rock music" music conspiracies"
REM SET "categories=conspiracies music"
:: set up sorting categories
SET "sortingcategories="
FOR %%a IN (%categories%) DO CALL :addsc %%a
SET "sortingcategories=%sortingcategories: =_%"
:: Create "tempfile" containing lines of name|sortingcategory|weight
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=," %%s IN (q45196316.txt) DO (
 CALL :findfiles "%%s" "%%t" "%%u"
)
)>"%tempfile%"
SET "lastname="

SORT "%tempfile%">"%tempfile%.s"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2,3delims=|" %%a IN ("%tempfile%.s") DO (
 CALL :resolve %%b %%c "%%a"
)
:: and the last entry...
CALL :resolve dummy 0 

GOTO :EOF
:: resolve by totalling weights (%2) in sortingcategories (%1) 
:: for each name (%3)
:resolve
IF "%~3" equ "%lastname%" GOTO accum
:: report and reset accumulators
IF NOT DEFINED lastname GOTO RESET
SET "winner=none"
SET /a maxfound=0
FOR %%v IN (%sortingcategories%) DO CALL :findmax %%v
ECHO %winner:_= % %lastname:&=and%
:RESET
FOR %%v IN (%sortingcategories%) DO SET /a $%%v=0
SET "lastname=%~3"
:accum
SET /a $%1+=%2
GOTO :eof

:findmax
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=$=" %%w IN ('set $%1') DO IF %%x gtr %maxfound% (
 SET "winner=%1"
 SET /a maxfound=%%x
)
GOTO :eof

:: add sorting category
:addsc
SET "sortingcategories=%sortingcategories%,%~1"
GOTO :eof

:: Find all files matching %3.
:: They are in category %1 and have weight %2

:findfiles
SET "sortingcategory=%~1"
SET "sortingcategory=%sortingcategory: =_%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*%~3*" 2^>nul'
 ) DO (
  ECHO %%a^|%sortingcategory%^|%~2^|%~1^|%~3
)
GOTO :eof
```

This time, I've removed all of the `enabledelayedexpansion` processing, which is the root-cause of the problems with `!` and moved all of the processing that used to depend on `delayedexpansion` into subroutines. This is solely to deal with the `!` problem. I recall you had issues with `'` as well, but I couldn't find any problem with *that*, either in theory or practice.

Comment: Thanks, umm.. I'm gonna have to study this properly tomorrow.

Comment: Works great! That is some solid logic you got there. I wonder how you would extrapolate the series name from filename because my script of that is mad large and slow...

Comment: You learn a thing or two when you've been doing this variety of work for over 40 years. All I did for testing was to create a set of dummy files named like `seriesname S0E1.mp4` and vary the number after E, then make a routine that simply grabbed `seriesname`. OK for testing, but since you haven't revealed your filename convention or how you derive the seriesname from that filename, I have to rely on your existing routine (and guess what it does).

Comment: I just tried this with a larger amount of files and quickly realized that this is way slower than my original method since it has to run everything in the tree through my `lootname.cmd` script which is super slow. I added it into my original post so you can take a look.

Comment: I will look into your bit about the variable extrapolation tomorrow. It looks like a massive upgrade. I was sure most of that code was crude for you. Now I will post my own answer to my original question..

Comment: I finally incorporated this with a few fixes. I must say it's genius, I'm getting much better speeds now. Thank you so much! What do you think about my alternate solution for the primary script?

Comment: I am having some issues with special characters... investigating now

Comment: When a file has `!` in the filename the first end trimming with the episode tag fails. The ending of the filename is correctly trimmed so later tags are recorded correctly but the first one is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
@cd /d d:\videos\series
@if /i not "%cd%"=="d:\videos\series" echo invalid series dir. && exit /b
@if not exist "pilot episodes" echo pilot episodes dir missing. && exit /b
@if not exist "d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd" echo lootname missing. && exit /b
@for %%i in (*) do @call :processing "%%i"
@exit /b

:processing
@if not exist %1 exit /b
@call d:\other\scripts\lootname.cmd "%~n1" data

:: move if dir exists. perfect.
@if exist "%name%" move %1 "%name%\" >nul && echo "%~dp1%name%\%~nx1" && exit /b

:: new. find and count possible others.
@set "count=0" & set "dots=%name: =.%"
@for %%i in ("%name% s*" "%dots%.s*") do @set /a count+=1
@for /r "pilot episodes" %%i in ("%name% s*" "%dots%.s*") do @set /a count+=1

:: move if single, pilot
@if "%count%"=="0" echo fatar error while pairing "%name%" && exit /b
@if "%count%"=="1" echo %1 | find /i "01e01" >nul && move %1 "pilot episodes\" >nul && echo "%~dp1pilot episodes\%~nx1" && exit /b

:: move set to new folder
@mkdir "%name%"
@for /r %%i in ("%name% s*" "%dots%.s*") do @move "%%i" "%name%\" >nul
@dir /s /b "%name%"
```

This does the bare minimum amount of work and seems to do it correctly (according to very basic testing). Sorry for the use of `@`, I like it this way so when there is an error I can enable just the part where I suspect the bug is.